# Fill up form with existing data is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter

I start flutter recently. I want to fill up the form with existing data but the two dropdown is not filled up by existing data. I struggled for couple of hours to fix this but no luck. Here is my complete code:

```
import 'package:awesome_select/awesome_select.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/data/service.dart';
import '../common/bottom_navigation.dart';
import '../common/floating_button.dart';
import '../widget/TextInput.dart';

class NewPickupPoint extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/newPickupPointPage';
  const NewPickupPoint({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewPickupPoint> createState() => _NewPickupPointState();
}

class _NewPickupPointState extends State<NewPickupPoint> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  bool showform = false;
  List<S2Choice<int>> districts = [];
  List<S2Choice<int>> areas = [];
  List userPickupPoint = [];
  bool loadingDistrict = false;
  bool loadingUpazilla = false;
  bool loadingExistingData = false;
  int districtId = 0;
  int areaId = 0;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Service().getPickupAddress(context).then((response) {
      setState(() {
        nameController.text = response['title'];
        addressController.text = response['street'];
        districtId = response['district'];
        areaId = response['upazilla'];
        loadingExistingData = true;
      });
    });
    updateDistrictList();
    updateAreaList(districtId);
  }

  updateDistrictList() async {
    var _futureOfList = Service().getDistrictList();
    List list = await _futureOfList;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        districts
            .add(S2Choice<int>(value: list[i]['id'], title: list[i]['name']));
        loadingDistrict = true;
      });
    }
  }

  updateAreaList(int? value) async {
    var _futureOfList = await Service().getAreaList(districtId, context);
    List list = await _futureOfList;
    List<S2Choice<int>> areaList = [];
    setState(() {
      list.forEach((element) {
        areaList
            .add(S2Choice<int>(value: element['id'], title: element['name']));
      });
      print(areaList);
    });
    setState(() {
      areas = areaList;
    });
  }

  setDistrictList() async {
    var _futureOfList = Service().getDistrictList();
    List list = await _futureOfList;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        districts
            .add(S2Choice<int>(value: list[i]['id'], title: list[i]['name']));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add new pickup point'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            // Card For Showing user pickup addresse
            Padding(
              padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10, horizontal: 30.0),
                      child: TextInput(
                        inputController: nameController,
                        label: 'Name of the pickup point',
                        icon: Icons.edit,
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (loadingDistrict && loadingExistingData)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10, horizontal: 30.0),
                        child: SmartSelect<int>.single(
                          modalFilter: true,
                          modalFilterAuto: true,
                          tileBuilder: (context, state) => S2Tile<dynamic>(
                            //https://github.com/akbarpulatov/flutter_awesome_select/blob/master/example/lib/features_single/single_chips.dart
                            title: const Text(
                              'District',
                            ),
                            value: state.selected?.toWidget() ?? Container(),
                            leading: Icon(Icons.list_outlined),
                            onTap: state.showModal,
                          ),
                          title: 'District',
                          placeholder: 'Select',
                          choiceItems: districts,
                          onChange: (state) {
                            setState(() {
                              districtId = state.value!;
                              updateAreaList(state.value).then((value) {
                                setState(() {});
                              });
                            });
                          },
                          selectedValue: districtId,
                        ),
                      ),
                    if (loadingExistingData)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10, horizontal: 30.0),
                        child: SmartSelect<int>.single(
                          modalFilter: true,
                          modalFilterAuto: true,
                          tileBuilder: (context, state) => S2Tile<dynamic>(
                            //https://github.com/akbarpulatov/flutter_awesome_select/blob/master/example/lib/features_single/single_chips.dart
                            title: const Text(
                              'এলাকা',
                            ),
                            value: state.selected?.toWidget() ?? Container(),
                            leading: Icon(Icons.list_outlined),
                            onTap: state.showModal,
                          ),
                          title: 'Area',
                          placeholder: 'Select',
                          choiceItems: areas,
                          onChange: (state) =>
                              setState(() => areaId = state.value!),
                          selectedValue: areaId,
                        ),
                      ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10, horizontal: 30.0),
                      child: TextInput(
                          inputController: addressController,
                          label: 'Detail Address',
                          icon: Icons.map_outlined),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'For example: House 118/D, Road: 05, Mohanagar Project, Dhaka',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _savePickupPoint(context);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Save'),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: !keyboardIsOpen,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 45,
          ),
          child: floating(context),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }

  void _savePickupPoint(BuildContext context) {
    Service().addPickupPoint(nameController.text, districtId, areaId,
        addressController.text, context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. By setting the initial value of a formcontrol

```
TextFormField(
  initialValue: 'The value you want to show',
)
```

2. By setting the controller value immediately after geeting the value. If can be in the Init method or before the builder method

```
_yourController.text = "The value you want to show";
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. You can see problem is with my dropdown and selectedValue: districtId. I have to use this syntax to update selected value of dropdown. And I update the districtId inside initState() method.